# Sorting in MongoDB's aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

[The docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/sort/) for MongoDB seem to suggest that in order to sort the results of an `aggregate` call you should specify a dictionary/object like this:

```
db.users.aggregate(
    { $sort : { age : -1, posts: 1 } }
);
```

This is supposed to sort by `age` and then by `posts`.

What do I do if I want to sort by `posts` and then by `age`? Changing the order of the keys seems to have no effect, probably because this is a JS object's properties. In other words, sorting, it seems, is always according to the lexical order of the keys, which seems rather odd as a design choice...

Am I missing something? Is there a way to specify an **ordered** list of keys to sort by?

Comment: Seems to work in the shell.  Are you doing this in the shell or in a node.js program?

Comment: Doing this in python using the standard driver.

Comment: I assume this is just part of a more complex example, but just this query could be done with ``db.users.find().sort({ age : -1, posts: 1 })``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html?highlight=aggregate#aggregation-framework):

> As python dictionaries don’t maintain order you should use `SON` or
>   `collections.OrderedDict` where explicit ordering is required eg
>   "$sort"

```py
from bson.son import SON
db.users.aggregate([
    {"$sort": SON([("posts", 1), ("age", -1)])}
])
```